# initWithNibName crash

Tags: iphone, crash

My app started crashing lately I need some help to figure it out why.

In the app delegate I create a navigation controller

```
UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];
```

And then load into 3 controllers (1 shown)

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController;
secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 

[initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];

[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];
[localNavigationController release];
[secondViewController release];
```

One of the view has a button that calls an action that pushes a new view

```
Ref *third = [[Ref alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fourthview" bundle:nil];
```

so far so good. I have updated an older xib that now I want to use but the app is crashes as soon as it pushed

```
Sup *third = [[Sup alloc] initWithNibName:@"Fifthview" bundle:nil];
```

If I go to IB and disconnect all UILabel Outlet it will work. But connecting for example pName will crash

Here's the error

'[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pName.'

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Sup`, which is being used to load the `Fifthview` XIB, must have either a property or an ivar named `pName`. This is probably due to an IBOutlet in the XIB that connects a `pName` property to File's Owner.

The XIB loading process is attempting to use KVC to connect all of the IBOutlets defined in the XIB, which in practice means it's calling `-[setValue:forKey:]` where the key is equal to `@"pName"`. If you already have a `pName` property declared in `Sup`, make sure you also have `@synthesize pName;` somewhere in the implementation in `Sup.m`.

Comment: You were the first one so you got the point. However it was a typo. Just spent another half hour chasing my own tail :-) The XIB file name was incorrect.